# send get data in url without question mark or ampersand

Tags: php, get

I want to send verification code to my user after registration to their email by sending url like

http://www.example.com/emailverify.php?verification_code=01613fd015ada97f9f67cec5431b98e5

or

http://www.example.com?page_id=115&verification_code=01613fd015ada97f9f67cec5431b98e5

is there any way to send get data without ? or &

like

http://www.example.com/email_verify/verification_code=01613fd015ada97f9f67cec5431b98e5

I am using wordpress.So email verify page permalink is 
http://www.example.com/email_verify/

Comment: Why would you need to do that ?

Comment: There are countless ways this can be done. Do some research and you'll find a solution that suits your needs. try searching for `apache rewrite` or `php clean url` or `php router`

Answer (score 1):

You could [rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) the URL in your web-server.

For example, you give out a link like http://www.example.com/email_verify/verification_code/1234abcd.  When your web-server gets the request, it rewrites it into http://www.example.com/email_verify.php?verification_code=1234abcd.